# mod_pagespeed & Virtualmin - mod_pagespeed only active on one virtualhost

Tags: apache

I've installed mod_pagespeed on a server running Virtualmin. Mod_pagespeed is only active on the first virtualhost (Alphabetically).

How do I enable mod_pagespeed for all virtualhosts in a Virtualmin environment? I have seen the documentation at the following link, but I'm not sure how to use it in my situation.

https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/configuration#virtual-hosts